# display only one comment in node page

Tags: nodes, comments, paging

I'd like to display only 1 comment (the most recent one) in node page.
And I don't want the pager to be displayed too.

Is there any way to do it without writing custom module?

Could I use mytheme_preprocess_page($variables){} for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply set comments per page to 1. you can see settings in content type edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install and configure "[Comment goodness](http://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness)" module - it will allow you to sort comments to display newest first.

Then in your template.php create.

```
function THEME_preprocess_comment_wrapper(&$variables) {
   // Remove pager.  
   unset ($variables['content']['comments']['pager']);
   // Leave only latest comment.
   $last_comment_id = reset(element_children($variables['content']['comments']));
   $variables['content']['comments'] = array (
     $last_comment_id => $variables['content']['comments'][$last_comment_id]
   );
}
```